# Visual Studio 2010 Cannot save changes "Access To the Path is denied"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, access-denied, access-rights

I actually read some answers to a similar question, but the suggestions did not help very much. 
I have this VM with a 2010 VB application I need to configure some methods and make changes into the config files. It does not work as I get Access to the path is denied. My project is saved in D drive, and I had followed this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/894433/you-may-receive-an-access-is-denied-error-message-when-you-try-to-debu) and changed the local security settings, but did not help. 
I'm just running out of new idea. I'm local admin on this Windows server 2008 R2.

Comment: `I need to configure some methods and make changes into the config files` - Which tells us pretty much nothing. What _exactly_ is it you're trying to do? What file(s) are you trying to change and where are they located? Please show us your code.

Comment: @Visual vincent, can i start a discussion with u?How do i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 is stupid, it seems when one start it it does not understand that the user has admin rights unless you start it form the "Start Menu" => right click and start it as admin.
In my case I was starting the solution from the directory where it was stored, and when right click I don't get the option to start it as admin.

Comment: That behavior is by design in Windows for security reasons. An application only gets admin rights if started explicitly in that way or successfully asks for elevation and is granted by the user. It's [called UAC.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742497(v=vs.85).aspx) Best practices suggest it's not ideal to run in admin mode unless absolutely necessary so no app starts in this way by default regardless of the underlying account being used by the user.